# jquery click event to swap text not firing on first click but works after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I'm new to javascript and jquery, and I have this little bit of code to swap one bit of text for another that works perfectly *except* for the very first time you click the div.

Any ideas? I'm probably just calling on it wrong but not sure how to proceed

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pauljackson/4r8v6/

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showemail").click(function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        if ($self.text() == "Contact")
        $self.text("someguy@theinternet.com");
        else
        $self.text("Contact");
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="showemail">
Contact
</div>
```

css:

```
#showemail:hover {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Load your fiddle again and click the tidyup button, then run. Does it work now?

Comment: Tidying up the code isn't really a solution. At best you get a cleaner looking, incorrect piece of code.  As tymeJV mentioned, the contents of what he was targeting had extraneous data, white space. I think the overall lesson is when doing string comparison checks, know how your data is being returned by your getter function and adjust accordingly to your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your text has some whitespace originally, `trim` it:

```
if ($self.text().trim() == "Contact")
```

The reason it works the second click is because your `else` condition sets the `text` to "Contact" without whitespace - then the next time you click your condition evaluates to `true` and all is well

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4r8v6/3/

Answer (score 1):

Heres an update. Note the trim. It seems there is some additional text in the #showemail div that needs to be trimmed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showemail").click(function() {

        var $self = $(this);
        console.log($self.text());
        if ($self.text().trim() == "Contact") {
        $self.text("someguy@theinternet.com");
        }
        else {
        $self.text("Contact");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks to you as well sir!

Comment: Note the way I debugged this for yourself in future. You can use console.log to see what's happening or even use the javascript debugger in chrome/firefox to see how the code is being traversed.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the advice, that will come in handy